# How high can server load be before sendmail would not be able to function anymore

Tags: sendmail, high-load

I have a virtual server that runs multiple VPS on it, when we backup to a usb external hard drive the load increases to about 10 on the mail server with sendmail we get this in the log file

```
rejecting connections on daemon MTA: load average: 10
```

I know it is trying to easy the load on the server by not taking on any new connections and I know how to increase the value in the config file.
My question is how high can I set it before I will loose mail?

I also use fetchmail and I am not sure what happens to the mail if it fetches it and then sendmail does not accept it.

So high can I make the load and what happens to the mail if fetchmail fetched it and cant hand it off to sendmail?

This only happens late at night when we do the backups.

```
[root@sogo ~]# grep 'LA=' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
O QueueLA=8
O RefuseLA=10
#O DelayLA=0
```

Comment: 1) Could you include LA limits from your `sendmail.cf`?  `grep 'LA=' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` 2) Have you tried to capture peak LA (load average) during backup?  On most installations RefuseLA/QueueLA/DelayLA may be safely increased but IMHO it is better to increase them as little as possible.

Comment: @ Andrzej I added it to the question, will check graphs this weekend and see regarding how high it goes